# How to set Firefox preference for selfsign cerificats in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am working on robotframework and stuck with login screen because my application is using selfsign certificates, How I can set the flag for accept all certificates programmaticaly? I tried to create FireFox profile and set

```
fp.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs",True)
```

But It didn't work.
I know that there is workaround after manually accept certificates but I don't want to do it manually.

My Python code is looks like

```
def create_profile(path):
    from selenium import webdriver
    fp =webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=path)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    fp.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs",True)
    fp.set_preference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", False)
    fp.update_preferences()
    return fp.path
```

And robot Test case is looks like

```
Launch Infoscale Access
    ${random_string} =  Generate Random String  8
    ${path} Catenate    SEPARATOR=\\    ${EXECDIR}  ${random_string}
    Create Directory    ${path}
    ${profile} =    create_profile  ${path}
    Log ${path}
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}  ff_profile_dir=${profile}
```

Below is version of libraries which I am using
python2.7
selenium2.32.0
robotframework2.6.0
geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64

Comment: Show some more lines of code before and after provided line

Comment: @Andersson Hi , I edit the post with code block, hope it can help to understand and reproduce this issue. I found this link https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/93 .. Not sure, Is it the same issue which hit by me?

Comment: Can you also try `fp.set_preference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris","DESIREDURL")`?

Comment: Hi @Andersson, I tried it but no success.